# Sidebar Menu Toggle AND Push Content

Tags: javascript, menu, navigation, toggle, sidebar

OK yall I have been working with this code for several days.. I'm trying to use my  hamburger toggle to open/close the side menu AND push my content to the right.. What do I need to add to my toggleNAV() JS function to make this happen? Thanks

```
 <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">


 <a href="#">About</a>
 <a href="#">Services</a>
 <a href="#">Clients</a>
 <a href="#">Contact</a>
 </div>

 <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this);toggleNav();">
 <div class="bar1"></div>
 <div class="bar2"></div>
 <div class="bar3"></div>
 </div>

    <script>function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
        }</script>


    <script>
   function toggleNav() {
var element = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
if (element.style.width == "250px") {
    element.style.width = "0px";
} else {
    element.style.width = "250px";
}
}

    </script>
```

and here's my CSS

```
  .sidenav {
   height: 100%;
   width: 0;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 4444444444444444444;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: #111;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   transition: 0.5s;
   padding-top: 60px;
   }

  .sidenav a {
   padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 25px;
   color: #818181;
   display: block;
   transition: 0.3s;
   }

  .sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
   color: #f1f1f1;
   }



  #main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  }

  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
 .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
 .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
  }


  .button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 444444444444444444;

   }
   .container {
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 4444444444444;
    }

 .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  }

  /* Rotate first bar */
 .change .bar1 {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
 transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
 }

 /* Fade out the second bar */
 .change .bar2 {
 opacity: 0;
  }

 /* Rotate last bar */
.change .bar3 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
 transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide existing css?

Comment: OK i added CSS !

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant, but it's working - try to add some [CSS3 transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for a smoother toggle.

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}

function toggleNav() {
  var element = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
  var main = document.getElementById("main-content");
  if (element.style.width == "250px") {
    element.style.width = "0px";
    main.style.left = "0px";
  } else {
    element.style.width = "250px";
    main.style.left = "250px";
  }
  $()
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2147483647; /* thats max (−2147483648 to +2147483647) */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 444444444444444444;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4444444444444;
  
}

#main-content {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  position: fixed;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  float:left;
}


/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Rotate last bar */

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  position: fixed;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="container" onclick="toggleNav();">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id="main-content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm not sure that `z-index:4444444444444444` is reliable.
Your menu doesn't push the rest to the right for 1 reason : they're not on the same z-index.

Plus, I'd rather not animate the width since it can be really weird sometimes, even more if you do it with basic CSS.

What I'd recommend is changing your POV regarding sidemenus :

(for this your page and sidemenu must be positionned `absolute` and body `relative`)

What if your sidemenu was actually below your page and you only transition the left position of your page.

Or they could be on the same level but your sidemenu is on the left and outta view by default, therefore you move both to the right when clicked.

What I mean by those is that you can work something out with :

```
body{
  position : relative;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  /* ... */
}

.mySideMenuClass{
  position : absolute;
  z-index : 0;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:/*some width (named SMw for later)*/
  /* ... */
}

.myPageClass{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition: all /*some duration*/s ease-in-out;
  /* ... */
}

.myPageClass.SMtoggled{
  left:/*SMw*/;
  /* ... */
}
```

and just toggleClass the thingie.

This is not a complete solution but you get the idea now at your keyboard ;) !

Comment: So if I set the Z index of my canvas layer at the same value as my content I can push the canvas as well???

Comment: z-index, as its name indicates, is where it's positionned on the z-axis therefore you can think of an element that as a z-index as a box where you put things in it (accurate for the "z-index paradox"). If you add an element `z-index:50` into a container `z-index:0` and you move the container then (correct me if I'm wrong) the element follows its container

Answer (score 0):

thanks yall, here's what i worked out..

```
function toggleNav() {
var element = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
if (element.style.width == "250px") 
{(document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0");
    (element.style.width = "0px");
 } else {
    (element.style.width = "250px");
 (document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "350px");
 }
 }
```